# Django CMS - Structure mode does not have scroll bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-cms

I created a Django CMS based website and created pages then added elements (plugins).

> Python 2.7.15, Django<2.0, django-cms>=3.5,<3.6

The default **requirements.txt** file generated had the following dependencies in it.

```
django-cms>=3.5,<3.6
djangocms-admin-style>=1.2,<1.3
django-treebeard>=4.0,<5.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor>=3.6.0
djangocms-link>=2.1
djangocms-style>=2.0
djangocms-googlemap>=1.1
djangocms-snippet>=2.0
djangocms-video>=2.0
djangocms-column>=1.7
djangocms-file>=2.0,<3.0
djangocms-picture>=2.0,<3.0
easy_thumbnails
django-filer>=1.3
Django<2.0
pytz
django-classy-tags>=0.7
html5lib>=0.999999,<0.99999999
Pillow>=3.0
django-sekizai>=0.9
six
```

I was able to see/edit etc. In latest version of Django CMS, it has an icon on far right corner to toggle between Structure/Content mode.

The main problem that I faced is, when the structure mode is filled with number of elements (plugins), I was unable to edit the elements available at very bottom as there is no scroll bar to visit those elements (Like they are jsut below & behind the taskbar).

It is clear in the below image link.

[Structure mode issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ixS.png)

I searched for solutions but I failed.

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue or suggest me any other Django CMS version that I should go with?

Answer (score 1):

It may sound a bit silly, but have you tried scrolling with mousewheel while hovering over the structure? The scrollbar is hidden via css so that browser doesn't display two scrollbars.

If that doesn't work, it would be great if you could open an issue at github.com/divio/django-cms with details about your browser / setup and maybe a minimal test project to reproduce.

In the meantime you could also open structure as a separate view, e.g. "domain/en/my-page?structure".